# Need browse button on my JSP page to select folder (not files)

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsp

Here is kind of example what I want on my JSP page,

[image]

I can browse a file, but the requirement is to browse a folder.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

There's the [`HTMLInputElement.webkitdirectory`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/webkitdirectory) attribute you can add to `input` element. It is non-standard implementation; provide a fallback when using it.

Here's a snippet:

```js
function onFolderChange({ target }) {

  const files = target.files;

  // file is a FileList, array methods are not supported.
  [...files].forEach(console.log); // Needs a recursive function since `file` could be another FileList (a folder)

}


const folderInput = document.getElementById("folderInput");

folderInput.addEventListener('change', onFolderChange);
```

```html
<label>
   Select a folder
   <input id="folderInput" type="file" webkitdirectory directory multiple>
</label>
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response, but it did not meet my requirement. Its still showing the select file icon. I need browse button with text area.

Comment: <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function HandleBrowseClick()
{
    var fileinput = document.getElementById("browse");
    fileinput.click();
    var textinput = document.getElementById("filename");
    textinput.value = fileinput.value;
}
</script>

<input type="file" id="browse" name="fileupload" style="display: none"/>
<input type="text" id="filename" readonly="true"/>
<input type="button" value="Click to select file" id="fakeBrowse" onclick="HandleBrowseClick();"/>

Comment: Thank you so much. Sorry I was out for few days.  I tried above code. Again it works for file, not not for Folders. Do you have any example with CSS.